# Complexity of a SAT related problem

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, propositional-logic

Given a set of (propositional) formulae $\Phi$, two formulae $\phi$ and $\xi$, determine whether there exists $\Psi\subseteq \Phi$ such that $\Psi\models \phi$ and $\Psi\not\models \xi$.

Question: what is the (theoretical) complexity of this problem? Is it in [DP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dp)?

Comment: can you describe the notation in words? what is DP?

Comment: [Crossposted](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32045/complexity-of-a-generalization-of-sat-unsat) on cstheory.SE

Comment: I found the definition of DP: http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/papers/pdf/ALRch29.pdf and search for "is the class of languages A". DP is the class of languages A such that A = A1 ∩ A2 for some languages A1 in NP and A2
in co-NP.

Comment: @D.W., they are sets so is there a reason not to read it simply as "subset"? Also you can find the definition of [DP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dp) on complexity zoo.

Comment: @Kaveh, you're right, I mis-read.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Given a propositional formula $\varphi(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$, consider $\psi = \exists \vec{y} \ \forall \vec{x} \ \varphi(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$.

Let 
$\Delta = 
\{ y_0 \leftrightarrow \top, y_0 \leftrightarrow \bot, \ldots, 
y_m \leftrightarrow \top, y_m \leftrightarrow \bot \}$.
Then $\psi$ is true iff there exists $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$ such that $\Gamma \nvDash \bot$ and $\Gamma \vDash \varphi(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$.

Therefore the problem is $\Sigma^\mathsf{P}_2$-hard.
$\mathsf{DP} \subseteq \Delta^\mathsf{P}_2$, so unless $\mathsf{PH}$ collapses the problem is not in $\mathsf{DP}$.